# Clustering algorithm for categorical data

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data-set with data in following format:

[image: Format of data]

Basically, data represents whether a particular word is present in that file or not. So say If file with doc-id 1 contains word1 then we put 'Yes' else 'No'. I need to cluster this files in k clusters.

Now here attributes are categorical (i.e. Yes or No) except docid column which I remove in preprocessing. I tried various clustering algorithms (ROCK, K-Modes etc) in WEKA and R for clustering this data but in most of them almost all files are forming a single cluster with rest k-1 clusters getting only 1 or 2 doc-ids.

My question is which clustering algorithm would be best for such data and why my data is forming a single cluster with almost all documents and rest clusters remaining sparse?

Comment: Appears you advice on basic text-mining, but you do need to do your "homework" since there is quite a bit of prior work and you should have displayed greater evidence of searching. I substituted one of your more general search terms with a specific R-package name.

Answer (score 0):

Try **frequent itemset mining**.

This approach makes usually much more sense on *sparse* *binary* data. In particular, it is more robust to noise - and apparently noise is your problem.